# Button onClick event not firing inside a repeater which is in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, postback, viewstate

I know I am missing something simple but I can't seem to get my button to post back. This is how my form looks (simplified):

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="smMembersArea" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />
<asp:UpdatePanel id="updAccounts" runat="server" EnableViewState="True">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater id="rptrWishList" runat="server" EnableViewState="False">
      <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button id="bWLAmend" onclick="FEdit" runat="server" cssclass="button bg" EnableViewState="True" Text="GO"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The update panel doesn't do anything and nothing happens in `FEdit`.

When I remove the updatepanel my FEdit event is triggered correctly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you put a breakpoint in FEdit and run this with the debugger to see if it definitely is not being called?

Comment: I am using Delphi and am not able to debug however nothing spits out in my windows debug log when I do this (which I am putting an entry in for this call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is add CommandName="Select" to your button

so your button now looks like this

```
<asp:Button id="bWLAmend" onclick="FEdit" runat="server" cssclass="button bg" EnableViewState="True" Text="GO" CommandName="Select"/>
```

and use itemcommand of the repeater rptrWishList_ItemCommand

so when you click the button, itemcommand event of repeater fires.

what language you are using in code behind..?I may be able to suggest something else.